# bgp filtering based on conjunction of prefix-list and as-path originator

Tags: bgp

Is there any way of having a filter that uses as-path origin and prefix-list together. For example I want to accept updates from origin of AS 5745 and prefix-list is say 189.150.20.X/24. Any other prefix from origin AS 5745 will be denied.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you directly connected to AS 5745?

Comment: No, it is few hops away.

Comment: I forgot to mention AS 5745 here originator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Cisco IOS, You can have more than one match criteria, and they will be processed as a logical AND.

For example

```
Route-map mymap permit 10
 Match as-path access-list abc
 Match ip prefix-list def
```

The route map will only match prefixes that match abc AND def.

For IOS-XR, there is a more flexible method than route- maps called RPL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tested it and got it working. Do you know if it possible to apply more than one route maps to the same neighbor?

Comment: or is it possible to process matching criterias as a logical or?

Comment: Yes you can  add another stanza: route-map mymap permit 20

Comment: But how do I apply them to the same peer? It looks like last route map is overriding the earlier ones when multiple route map is applied. Or is there anything like `match route-map` filter to combine multiple route-maps under the single one, so I can apply this to peer?

Comment: If the prefix doesn’t match mymap 10, it will try it against mymap 20.  You can add as many stanzas as you like.

Comment: @user3143318 You can apply 1 route-map per neighbor in each direction. So, you could have one for inbound and one for outbound, on the same neighbor. You cannot have more than 1 route-map applied in the same direction for a neighbor.  Like Ron said, though, so you can just add a new sequence/stanza to the existing route-map to add more match criteria.